# I can't found metadata column with a Websites content source type

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-2019

I have a problem with a content source which is Websites type in a SharePoint Server 2019 farm.
If I use a "SharePoint sites" content source type, I can get the value of a metadata column field. But if I use a "Websites" content source type, I can't access to this column. In my case, is mandatory to use a "Websites" content source type because it's a public portal.
I have too some rules to exclude the typical urls:
[Search rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUGRf.png)

Any ideas why I can't get the value with that content source and what I need to change to get it?

Thanks in advance!

Changes the rules, use other type of content source.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between “SharePoint sites” and “Websites” content source types is that the former crawls SharePoint sites only, while the latter crawls any website that you specify. SharePoint sites have a predefined set of metadata properties that are mapped to crawled properties, such as ContentTypeId, Author, and Title. Websites, on the other hand, may not have these metadata properties or may have different ones depending on the site structure and content.

Therefore, if you want to get the value of a metadata column field from a website, you need to make sure that the website has that metadata property and that it is mapped to a crawled property in the search schema. You can use the Search Schema tool in SharePoint to manage the mapping of crawled and managed properties. Alternatively, you can use the Content Enrichment web service to add or modify metadata properties for crawled items.

You can refer this link to [manage the search schema in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema).

Comment: I have on "SharePoint sites" type too, and I can get the metadata properties easily but in my case, I need to get the value with a "Websites" type and as I know the search service it's impossible to get the value. With the sharepoint sites content source I can create a managed property and assign the value from the crawled property, but when I crawl with the websites content source, the crawled property doesn't appear and I want to know if it's possible to get this crawled property or it's impossible and I need to use a "SharePoint sites" content source and filter the result from the search.